# How to optimise my AVX Code

Tags: c++, vectorization, simd, avx, auto-vectorization

I tried to translate the following code into AVX intrinsics in order to improve the performance:

```c
for (int alpha = 0; alpha < 4; alpha++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        for (int beta = 0; beta < 4; beta++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < 4 ; l++) {
                d2_phi[(alpha*3+k)*16 + beta*4+l] =
                    -   (d2_phi[(alpha*3+k)*16 + beta*dim+l]

                        +   b[k] * (  lam_12[ beta][alpha] *   a[l] 
                                    + lam_22[alpha][ beta] *   b[l] 
                                    + lam_23[alpha][ beta] * rjk[l]  )

                        + rjk[k] * (  lam_13[ beta][alpha] *   a[l] 
                                    + lam_23[ beta][alpha] *   b[l] 
                                    + lam_33[alpha][ beta] * rjk[l]  )
                        ) / sqrt_gamma;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and tried this the following way:

```c
// load sqrt_gamma, because it is constant
__m256d ymm7 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&sqrt_gamma);        

for (int alpha=0; alpha < 4; alpha++) {
    for (int k=0; k < 3; k++) {
        // Load values that are only dependent on k
        __m256d ymm9 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(b+k);   // all   b[k]
        __m256d ymm8 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(rjk+k); // all rjk[k]

        for (int beta=0; beta < 4; beta++) {
            // Load the lambdas, because they will stay the same for nine iterations
            __m256d ymm15 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(lam_12_p + 4*beta + alpha);   // all lam_12[ beta][alpha]
            __m256d ymm14 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(lam_22_p + 4*alpha + beta);   // all lam_22[alpha][ beta]
            __m256d ymm13 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(lam_23_p + 4*alpha + beta);   // all lam_23[alpha][ beta]
            __m256d ymm12 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(lam_13_p + 4*beta + alpha);   // all lam_13[ beta][alpha]
            __m256d ymm11 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(lam_23_p + 4*beta + alpha);   // all lam_23[ beta][alpha]
            __m256d ymm10 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(lam_33_p + 4*alpha + beta);   //     lam_33[alpha][ beta]   

            // Load the values that depend on the innermost loop, which is removed do to AVX
            __m256d ymm6 =_mm256_load_pd(a);   //   a[i] until   a[l+3]
            __m256d ymm5 =_mm256_load_pd(b);   //   b[i] until   b[l+3]
            __m256d ymm4 =_mm256_load_pd(rjk); // rjk[i] until rjk[l+3]
            //__m256d ymm3 =_mm256_load_pd(d2_phi_p + (alpha*3+k)*16  + beta*dim); // d2_phi[(alpha*3+k)*12 + beta*dim] until d2_phi[(alpha*3+k)*12 + beta*dim +3]
            __m256d ymm3 =_mm256_load_pd(d2_phi_p + 4*s);
            // Block that is later on multiplied with b[k]
            __m256d ymm2 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm15, ymm6); // lam_12[ beta][alpha] * a[l]
            __m256d ymm1 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm14, ymm5); // lam_22[alpha][ beta] * b[l];

            __m256d ymm0 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm2, ymm1);  // lam_12[ beta][alpha] * a[l] + lam_22[alpha][ beta]*b[l];

            ymm2 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm13, ymm4);         // lam_23[alpha][ beta] * rjk[l]
            ymm0 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm2, ymm0);          // lam_12[ beta][alpha] * a[l] + lam_22[alpha][ beta]*b[l] + lam_23[alpha][ beta] * b[i];

            ymm0 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm9, ymm0);          // b[k] * (first sum of three)


            // Block that is later on multiplied with rjk[k]
            ymm2 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm12, ymm6); // lam_13[ beta][alpha] *  a[l]
            ymm1 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm11, ymm5); // lam_23[ beta][alpha] *  b[l]

            ymm2 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm2, ymm1);  // lam_13[ beta][alpha] *  a[l] + lam_22[alpha][ beta]*b[l];

            ymm1 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm10, ymm4); // lam_33[alpha][ beta] * rjk[l]
            ymm2 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm2, ymm1);  // lam_13[ beta][alpha] *  a[l] + lam_22[alpha][ beta]*b[l] + lam_33[alpha][ beta] *rjk[l]

            ymm2 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm2, ymm8);  // rjk[k] * (second sum of three)
            ymm0 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm0, ymm2);  // add to temporal result in ymm0
            ymm0 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm3, ymm0);  // Old value of d2 Phi;

            ymm0 = _mm256_div_pd(ymm0, ymm7);   // all divided by sqrt_gamma

            _mm256_store_pd(d2_phi_p + (alpha*3+k)*16  + beta*dim, ymm0);
        }
    }
}
```

But the peformance is bad. It is even slower than auto-vectorized code generated by Intel compiler. I tried the following things:

- All data arrays are 64-byte aligned by `__declspec(align(64))`
- The store at the end was replaced by a streaming store `_mm256_stream_pd`

When I look into the created assembly code, I see, that the auto-code fetches all parameters every iteration (and not as I did, only in the loops they belong to). It also contains more arithmetic operations. As a last point the store at the end only need half of the time of mine (I repeat the code fragment 1000000 times) and I don't see a reason for that. (I used the Intel VTune Amplifier to look at the assembly and the spent time.)

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: Why not generate an assembly listing from the auto-vectorized code and use that as a starting point and see if you can improve on it?

Comment: I have the assembly already. But as I stated I am confused, because it fetches the data more offen, it does not use load/store instructions for aligned data, although it is aligned and as the main point: I don't get, why the storage there is faster, although in both cases a instruction like 
vmovupd ymmword ptr [ecx+0x408fc0], ymm6
is executed.

Comment: Get rid of the division, obviously. Multiply by the reciprocal.

Comment: It's removed now, and I get the same performance as the auto-vectorization. But I'm still slower although in the auto-vectorized assembler there is still a division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm putting this here as a second answer, as it is a different and much more extensive optimisation. The key is to [change the order of the loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization) to reduce the number of redundant operations by hoisting many of the loads and arithmetic operations out of the innermost loop.

Original loop structure:

```
for (int alpha=0; alpha < 4; alpha++) {
    for (int k=0; k < 3; k++) {
        for (int beta=0; beta < 4; beta++) {
            for (int l=0; l < 4 ; l++) {
```

New loop structure:

```
for (int alpha=0; alpha < 4; alpha++) {
    for (int beta=0; beta < 4; beta++) {
        for (int k=0; k < 3; k++) {
            for (int l=0; l < 4 ; l++) {
```

Complete tested and optimised implementation of your function:

```
static void foo(
    double lam_11[4][4],
    double lam_12[4][4],
    double lam_13[4][4],
    double lam_22[4][4],
    double lam_23[4][4],
    double lam_33[4][4],
    const double rjk[4],
    const double a[4],
    const double b[4],
    const double sqrt_gamma,
    const double SPab,
    const double d1_phi[16],
    double d2_phi[192])
{
    const double re_sqrt_gamma = 1.0 / sqrt_gamma;

    memset(d2_phi, 0.0, 192*sizeof(double));

    const __m256d ymm6 = _mm256_load_pd(a); // load the whole 4-vector 'a' into register

    {
        // load SPab, because it is constant
        const __m256d ymm0 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&SPab);
        const __m256d ymm7 = _mm256_load_pd(b); // load the whole 4-vector 'b' into register
        const __m256d ymm8 = _mm256_load_pd(rjk); // load the whole 4-vector 'rjk' into register

        for (int alpha=0; alpha < 4; alpha++)
        {
            for (int beta=0; beta < 4; beta++)
            {
                // Load the three lambdas to all
                const __m256d ymm3 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lam_11[alpha][beta]);
                const __m256d ymm4 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lam_12[alpha][beta]);
                const __m256d ymm5 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lam_13[alpha][beta]);

                const __m256d ymm9 = _mm256_load_pd(d1_phi + beta*4);

                // Do the three Multiplications
                const __m256d ymm13 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm4,ymm7); // lam_12[alpha][ beta] *  b[l] = PROD2
                const __m256d ymm14 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm5,ymm8); // lam_13[alpha][ beta] * rjk[l] = PROD3
                const __m256d ymm15 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm3,ymm6); // lam_11[alpha][ beta] *  a[l] = PROD1
                __m256d ymm12 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm15, ymm13); // PROD1 + PROD2 = PROD12
                ymm12 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm12, ymm14); // PROD12 + PROD3 = PROD123

                double* addr = d2_phi + alpha*3*16  + beta*dim;

                for (int k=0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    const __m256d ymm1 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&d1_phi[alpha*dim + k]); // load d1_phi[alpha*dim+k] to all
                    const __m256d ymm2 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&a[k]); // load a[k] to all
                    const __m256d ymm10 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm0, ymm1); // SPab * d1_phi[alpha*dim+k] = PRE
                    const __m256d ymm11 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm10, ymm9); // PRE * d1_phi[beta*dim+l] = SUM1

                    __m256d ymm12t = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm12, ymm2); // a[k] * PROD123 = SUM2
                    ymm12t = _mm256_add_pd(ymm11, ymm12t); // SUM1 + SUM2

                    _mm256_store_pd(addr, ymm12t);

                    addr+=16;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    {
        const __m256d ymm4 =_mm256_load_pd(rjk); // rjk[i] until rjk[l+3]
        const __m256d ymm5 =_mm256_load_pd(b); // b[l] until b[l+3]

        // load sqrt_gamma, because it is constant
        const __m256d ymm7 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&re_sqrt_gamma);

        for (int alpha=0; alpha < 4; alpha++)
        {
            for (int beta=0; beta < 4; beta++)
            {
                // Load the lambdas, because they will stay the same for nine iterations
                const __m256d ymm15 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lam_12[beta][alpha]);   // all lam_12[ beta][alpha]
                const __m256d ymm14 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lam_22[alpha][beta]);   // all lam_22[alpha][ beta]
                const __m256d ymm13 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lam_23[alpha][beta]);   // all lam_23[alpha][ beta]
                const __m256d ymm12 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lam_13[beta][alpha]);   // all lam_13[ beta][alpha]
                const __m256d ymm11 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lam_23[beta][alpha]); // all lam_23[ beta][alpha]
                const __m256d ymm10 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lam_33[alpha][beta]); // lam_33[alpha][ beta]

                __m256d ymm0, ymm1, ymm2;

                // Block that is later on multiplied with b[k]
                ymm2 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm15 , ymm6); // lam_12[ beta][alpha] *  a[l]
                ymm1 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm14 , ymm5); // lam_22[alpha][ beta] * b[l];
                ymm0 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm2, ymm1);   // lam_12[ beta][alpha]* a[l] + lam_22[alpha][ beta]*b[l];
                ymm2 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm13 , ymm4); // lam_23[alpha][ beta] * rjk[l]
                ymm0 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm2, ymm0);   // lam_12[ beta][alpha]* a[l] + lam_22[alpha][ beta]*b[l] + lam_23[alpha][ beta] * b[i];

                // Block that is later on multiplied with rjk[k]
                ymm2 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm12 , ymm6); // lam_13[ beta][alpha] *  a[l]
                ymm1 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm11 , ymm5); // lam_23[ beta][alpha] *  b[l]
                ymm2 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm2, ymm1);   // lam_13[ beta][alpha] *  a[l] + lam_22[alpha][ beta]*b[l];
                ymm1 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm10 , ymm4); // lam_33[alpha][ beta] * rjk[l]
                ymm2 = _mm256_add_pd(ymm2 , ymm1);  // lam_13[ beta][alpha] *  a[l] + lam_22[alpha][ beta]*b[l] + lam_33[alpha][ beta] *rjk[l]

                double* addr = d2_phi + alpha*3*16  + beta*dim;

                for (int k=0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    // Load values that are only dependent on k
                    const __m256d ymm9 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(b+k); // all b[k]
                    const __m256d ymm8 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(rjk+k); // all rjk[k]

                    // Load the values that depend on the innermost loop, which is removed do to AVX

                    const __m256d ymm3 =_mm256_load_pd(addr);

                    __m256d ymm0t, ymm1t, ymm2t;

                    // Block that is later on multiplied with b[k]

                    ymm0t = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm9 , ymm0); // b[k] * (first sum of three)

                    // Block that is later on multiplied with rjk[k]

                    ymm1t = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm2 , ymm8); // rjk[k] * (second sum of three)
                    ymm2t = _mm256_add_pd(ymm0t, ymm1t); // add to temporal result in ymm0
                    ymm1t = _mm256_add_pd(ymm3, ymm2t);  // Old value of d2 Phi;

                    ymm2t = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm1t, ymm7); // all divided by sqrt_gamma
                    ymm1t = _mm256_xor_pd(ymm2t, SIGNMASK);

                    _mm256_store_pd(addr, ymm1t);

                    addr += 16;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The original AVX code ran at around 500 ms with your test harness, the new version runs at around 200 ms, so that's a 2.5x throughput improvement.

Updated version of your test harness with original code and optimised code here: http://pastebin.com/yMPbYPjb

Comment: You have been busy! Congrats on being the first to earn the AVX tag.

Comment: Many many thanks Paul! It also much faster on my machine, when integrated into the program where it was taken from! Now I have to repeat some measurements to see the real performance gain on the system. Thanks again vor your great work!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with integration and testing - if you get a chance it would be interesting to hear how much performance gain you ultimately get overall.

Comment: Hi Paul, so after lots of testing now I get an improvement of about 40% in the whole application. The biggest testcase used so far, improved its performance from about 200000 seconds (> 55 h) to about 140000 seconds (39 h). So it is a huge performance increase. Thanks you again very very much.

Comment: @user3572032: thanks so much for getting back to me with the outcome - glad to have helped make a difference!

Comment: Could you please explain _how_ you were able to speed it up so well, what made the difference?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: it was about 5 years ago so I don’t remember the details, but it looks like it was mainly some kind of loop transformation to reduce the number of redundant operations. Loop transformations are a big topic, particularly in the context of compiler optimisations - these days a good compiler can do this kind of thing automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `VDIVPD` is expensive - it has a typical latency/throughput of the order of 20 - 40 cycles (exact figures depend on CPU). So one immediate change that I would suggest is to convert division by a constant into a multiplication, since `VMULPD` has a latency of only a few cycles and a single cycle throughput:

```
// load 1 / sqrt_gamma, because it is constant
const double re_sqrt_gamma = 1.0 / sqrt_gamma;
__m256d ymm7 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&re_sqrt_gamma);
```

...

```
ymm0 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm0, ymm7);   // all divided by sqrt_gamma
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! This sound very reasonable. I will try it and test it for the convergence of my algorithm! From the performance I can save nearly 15% of the runtime for 1000000 iterations.

Comment: It seems to have same numerical stability. But still now, I am only at the same level of performance as the auto-vectorization, which is using a division.

Comment: All I can suggest at this point is further careful study of the auto-vectorized code for clues - e.g. I wonder if ICC is clever enough to do advanced optimisations, such as re-ordering the loops? (Oh, and I'm sure you're already doing this, but you never know: you need to enable a suitable optimisation level for both versions, e.g. `-O3`).

Comment: The Vtune Amplifier still marks the _mm256_stream_pd as a hotspot and compared to the reference auto-vec-version the "_intel_memset"-function need lot of more time in my version. When I look at the assembly I can't figure out the compiler-magic that allows this speedup for saving...

Comment: I'm surprised that you're seeing calls to `_intel_memset` - is this for code outside the above function ? Also, have you checked that `_mm256_stream_pd` is better than `_mm256_store_pd` ? Do you have a test harness that I can play with and see if I can improve throughput ?

Comment: This may be for the initialization part, but this part is the same for both versions, so I don't understand way the time spent there differs in such a way. I have a single compilable cpp-file that includes initialization and both versions. How can I send it to you?

I use store and stream, but it does not make any difference in the runtime.

Comment: You could put the code somewhere like http://pastebin.com and then put a link to it here...

Comment: Thanks - I've hacked it around a little to work with my OS and compiler and I'm seeing around 900 ms for the scalar code and 500 ms for the AVX code - is that consistent with your results ?

Comment: At the moment I have nearly the same performance with O3 for both variants on an Xeon Ivy-Bridge (1230v2) with Intel compiler 14.0 and O3.

Comment: OK - what sort of figures are you seeing for timing and what is your CPU clock speed ? (I'm using a 2.6 GHz Haswell, BTW, and I'm using clang rather than ICC).

Comment: I raised the loopcount of the outer loop (over j) to j<1000
Then I get: 
Auto-vec-Code: 61 sec
AVX-Code: 52 sec

CPU is working at 3,7 GHz. Have to leave for today. Will be back tomorrow.

Comment: I've improved the AVX code now so that it's around 2.5x faster than the original - see separate answer for details.